# How to get height of ios home navigation line in the bottom of device?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

How can I get the height of this system line? it overlaps bottom of the application.
I want to get its height and set a padding to the bottom of whole application

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html widget solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
MediaQuery.viewPaddingOf(context).bottom
```